# Getting a singular value from a SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to fetch a value from one of my tables, however it doesn't appear to be retrieving it as when I echo the variable nothing is displayed.

Here is my code

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','neadatabase'); //Creating 
connection to database



//Connection Error Checking
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo ("Connection Successful");

//selecting bookings
$sqlSelectBookings = "
    SELECT ActivID, DateRequired, TimeRequired
    FROM activbooking
    WHERE ActivID = '$_POST[ActivID]' AND DateRequired = 
   '$_POST[DateRequired]' AND '$_POST[DateRequired]' AND 'TimeRequired = ' 
   $_POST[TimeRequired]'
";

$sqlSelectBookings = $conn->que($sqlSelectBookings);

//getting member limit
$sqlGetMemberLimit = "
    SELECT memberLimit
    FROM activity
    WHERE activID = '$_POST[ActivID]'
";

$sqlGetMemberLimit = ($conn->query($sqlGetMemberLimit)-
>fetchObject(memberLimit));

echo $sqlGetMemberLimit;
```

Any ideas?

[This is what happens when I run the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xay4.png)

Thanks

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements as described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: beside what @Alex says, have you checked value of 'ActivID' before the query ? where does it come from, and how did it get there ?

Comment: Ok, i've added the rest of my code - I wasn't fully sure what you meant @OldPadawan

Comment: 1st of all : where do $_POST[ActivID] come from ? any form with method=post ? then, on the page -> <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); $id = $_POST[ActivID]; echo"$id"; see result, and let us know...

Comment: The ActivID is a field in the Activity table, the user inputs this on the page before using a method=post form. I am selecting the activity record that has the activID of whatever the user inputs. Inside the Activity table there is another field called MemberLimit. I am trying to retrieve this variable, however the user would not know what this value is @OldPadawan

Comment: ok, seems that it *should not* be empty then, but nevertheless, have you tried and echo'd as stated in the previous comment ?